# How to override core abstract class in Illuminate Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I would like to override one particular method that exist in `Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand`'s Laravel core classes. It's an abstract class and many command classes like MakeControllerCommand, MakeFactoryCommand, MakeTestCommand, etc. Extends to this abstract class. I want to override the getArguments() method inside this abstract class without changing every default Make commands like:

- MakeControllerCommand
- MakeFactoryCommand
- MakeTestCommand

That in default, extends the `Illuminate\Console\GeneratorCommand` class.

```php
abstract class GeneratorCommand extends Command implements PromptsForMissingInput {
    ...

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return [
            ['name', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'The name of the '.strtolower($this->type)],
        ];
    }

    ...
}
```

Is it possible to do this by using Laravel Service Containers?

Comment: No, it won't be possible to swap the `GeneratorCommand` out as the other `Make` commands extend the class directly. The service container would only be used to swap an instance of a class that is resolved from it e.g. dependency injection,  with the use of  `app()` or `resolve()`, etc. What is it you're actually wanting to change in it?

Comment: I want to add optional parameter for all artisan commands, especially generator/make commands that i'm using. I want to add --module argument so every generated files can be placed in certain module folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to directly change the `GeneratorCommand` class at runtime because that class is used to extend the make commands and you can't override the inheritance of a class in that way.

If your purpose is to add arguments to these commands then the following might work if you add it in a service provider:

```
 public function boot() : void
    {
        $this->app->resolving(function (mixed $command, Application $app) {
            if ($command instanceof GeneratorCommand) {
                $command->addOption('module', null, \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, "Create this under specific module");
            }
        });
        Event::listen(CommandStarting::class, function (CommandStarting $event) {
            if ($module = $event->input->getParameterOption('--module')) {
                $modulePath = $this->app->basePath("modules/" . ucfirst($module));
                $this->app->useAppPath($modulePath);
                $this->app->useDatabasePath("$modulePath/Database");
                $this->app->changeNamespace(); // custom method added to Container
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, i could do that but it takes time to replace all of MakeCommand in Laravel, so i'm not going to do that, do you have another alternatives? Like maybe, overriding the method on the run time?

Comment: Using `resolving(GeneratorCommand::class` in the above might also work, or if that doesn't work using `->resolving(function ...)` without specific type will allow you to fire that every time something is resolved and check if it's of a type you are interested in

Comment: That resolving by closure helps me solves the problem

Comment: @AzvyaErstevan I modified your edit a bit to only affect `GeneratorCommand` instances (that applies to all classes that extend it as well) because checking if the class has `Make` in it is not future proof, i.e. commands that are not generator commands might end up containing it in the future and also in the future there might be commands that are generator commands that use something other than Make in their name.